# LocalStorage shoppingcart blazorServer error

Tags: c#, .net, local-storage, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'am following this tutorial https://www.appvnext.com/blog/2020/3/7/blazor-shopping-cart-sample-using-local-storage-to-persist-state, that is about "how to build a shopping cart with the local storage in blazor server". And in the section of "building the CartStateProvider component." I have this error :

**CartStateProvider.razor :**

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage;
@using ShoppingCartProjectServer.Data.Models;
@inject ProtectedLocalStorage ProtectedLocalStore

@code {
    public Cart ShoppingCart { get; set; } 
    bool hasLoaded;

    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        // The error appears right here below : CS0029
        ShoppingCart = await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<Cart>("ShoppingCart");

        if(ShoppingCart != null || ShoppingCart.Products.Count == 0)
        {
            ShoppingCart = new Cart();
        } else
        {
            hasLoaded = true;
        }
    }

    public async Task SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        await ProtectedLocalStore.SetAsync("ShoppingCart", ShoppingCart);
    }

}
```

CS0029 : Cannot implicitly convert type 'type' to 'type'

'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedBrowserStorageResult' in 'Cart'

Answer (score 0):

ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync does not return an object of the Cart class. You will need to do something like this:

```
var localCartValue = await ProtectedLocalStore.GetAsync<Cart>("ShoppingCart");
ShoppingCart = ConvertLocalStoreToCart(localCartValue);
```

ConvertLocalStoreToCart would create a new Cart object, assign it the values from the local storage, then return it. You'll have to write this depending on what is all involved with the Cart class.